# PdfGenerator EmailMessage EmailAttachment - Cannot access a closed Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, kentico

An error `System.ObjectDisposedException` with message `Cannot access a closed Stream` is being thrown when attempting to attach and send an `System.IO.MemoryStream` `EmailAttachment` to an `EmailMessage`. The attachment is being generated using [HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp). The attaching and sending is being done within a using statement.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf("<html><body>foo</body></html>", PdfSharp.PageSize.Letter);
    // 2nd argument is to NOT close stream
    pdf.Save(ms, false);

    EmailMessage em = new EmailMessage();
    em.EmailFormat = EmailFormatEnum.Html;
    em.From = "no-reply@foo.com";
    em.Recipients = "foo.bar@baz.net";
    em.Subject = "Attachment Name";
    em.Body = "There is an attachment";

    var attachment = new EmailAttachment(ms, "foo.pdf");
    em.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    // SiteContext.CurrentSiteName argument is just a site name required for Kentico CMS
    // true argument is send immediately
    EmailSender.SendEmail(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, em, true);    
}
```

If I do the following instead, it is successful the error does not occur as long as I do not attempt to `ms.Dispose()` within the `try` block:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
try
{
    var pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
    pdf.Save(ms, false);

    EmailMessage em = new EmailMessage();
    em.EmailFormat = EmailFormatEnum.Html;
    em.From = "no-reply@foo.com";
    em.Recipients = "foo.bar@baz.net";
    em.Subject = "Attachment Name";
    em.Body = "There is an attachment";

    var attachment = new EmailAttachment(ms, "foo.pdf");
    em.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    EmailSender.SendEmail(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, em, true);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    ms.Dispose();
}
```

The concern with the 2nd approach is that the `MemoryStream` is not being explicitly disposed. Is the `MemoryStream` inherently being disposed with this approach? If put `ms.Dispose();` **after** this entire block the same `Cannot access a closed Stream` occurs. Is this a memory leak waiting to happen? How can I dispose the `MemoryStream` without closing the stream to allow the email message to send the attachment?

Is this an issue with needing to somehow wait for `SendEmail()` to actually execute it's functionality?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come to a solution using the following code. It really may have been more of a Kentico CMS issue regarding the `sendImmediately` argument of `SendMail()`. By setting that to `false` (default), I was able to attach the stream as an `EmailAttachment` without the `System.ObjectDisposedException` error all within `using` statement.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, PdfSharp.PageSize.Letter);
    pdf.Save(ms, false);

    EmailMessage em = new EmailMessage();
    em.EmailFormat = EmailFormatEnum.Html;
    em.From = "no-reply@foo.com";
    em.Recipients = "foo.bar@baz.net";
    em.Subject = "Attachment Name";
    em.Body = "There is an attachment.";

    var attachment = new EmailAttachment(ms, "foo.pdf");
    em.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    // default sendImmediately of false
    EmailSender.SendEmail(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, em);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I dont follow why you want to dispose the ms in the try block, usually to clean up variables you use the finally block which it will be always executed whether there is an exception or not.
2. If you use the catch (that kind of catch with Exception catches all exceptions) you wont be getting errors because you are catching them

How you should do it is:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
try
{
    var pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
    pdf.Save(ms, false);

    EmailMessage em = new EmailMessage();
    em.EmailFormat = EmailFormatEnum.Html;
    em.From = "no-reply@foo.com";
    em.Recipients = "foo.bar@baz.net";
    em.Subject = "Attachment Name";
    em.Body = "There is an attachment";

    var attachment = new EmailAttachment(ms, "foo.pdf");
    em.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    EmailSender.SendEmail(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, em, true);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
ms.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: This should work. Thank you for the explanation. I was able to resolve the issue by adjusting an argument in the `SendEmail()` method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well you just need to close stream before accessing it from Kentico, i.e.:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, PdfSharp.PageSize.Letter);
    pdf.Save(ms, false);
}
```

And then you do your email part:

```
        EmailMessage em = new EmailMessage();
        em.EmailFormat = EmailFormatEnum.Html;
        em.From = "no-reply@foo.com";
        em.Recipients = "foo.bar@baz.net";
        em.Subject = "Attachment Name";
        em.Body = "There is an attachment.";
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
           var attachment = new EmailAttachment(ms, "foo.pdf");
           em.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        }
        EmailSender.SendEmail(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, em);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. If I have the `sendImmediately` (third argument) set to the `true`, I still get the `Cannot access a closed Stream` error even with the code you provided. I was able to resolve my issue with my original code by keeping `sendImmediately` as `false`. `SendEmail()` with `setImmediately` set to `true` only seems to work if the `MemoryStream` is not disposed.